# Recurrence function to print range of segment

Tags: algorithm, c++14, recurrence, segment-tree

I am trying to implement a simple recurrent function which conceptually similar to segment tree: each node represents a range `[l, r]` and if current node's index is `i`, its left and right child will have an index of `2i` and `2i+1` respectively. I implement a simple function to print the leaf nodes index (i.e. the segment range represented by the node is `[k, k]`) and its corresponding range as below:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

void recur(int l, int r, int idx){
    if(l > r) return;

    if(l == r) {
        cout << idx << ": " << l << " " << r << endl;
    }
    else {
        int mi = (l + r) >> 1;
        recur(l, mi, idx << 1);
        recur(mi+l, r, (idx << 1) + 1);
    }
}


int main() {
    recur(1, 10, 1);
    return 0;
}
```

I expect there will be 10 lines of outputs in the format of `[idx]: i i` where `i` ranges from 1 to 10. However the output is like below:

```
16: 1 1
17: 2 2
9: 3 3
10: 4 4
24: 6 6
```

I tried to debug for hours but have no luck, I wonder what would be the problem or is there any simpler way to implement the recurrence function as described?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo on this line:
`recur(mi+l, r, (idx << 1) + 1);`

Instead of `mi+l` it should be `mi+1`.

Comment: Oh my god silly me, thanks so much!